# How to apply iterative dfs for a graph which its node contains a subgraph inside

Tags: javascript, depth-first-search, blocking

As the title, I am working with a system structured as a graph, and the task is to expand from the initial node to the final node, and I have chosen the iterative DFS algorithm. Each node of the graph contains a nested subgraph within it. But my alogrithm cause blocking in JavaScript. 
Graph can be summarized like this: 
| system1  |   ---line1---->  |  system2 |   -----line2 --->    |  system3 |
---line3---->   |  system4 |

 system1 is inport, system2 is normal system, system3 is subsystem, and system4 is outport

For Detail, System3 is a Subsystem has a nested system in it, when i trace from system1 to system4, it go throught and go inside system3 and also trace from it's inport to it's outport, system3 inport found by line3 and line4 found by system3 outport.

```
// This function is used to initiate the trace from an 'inport' to an 'outport' within each 
//   subsystem.
async highlightSignal(input, systems, lines, lineDst) {
    var outport = [];
    var stack = [];

    // if system is found in current level, it found by "input", if system is
    // found when highlightSignal called to go inside a subsystem, it is found by   
   //  "lineDst"
    var s = findSystem()


    this.add(stack, s);
    outport = await this.TrackLoop( stack, input, systems, lines)
    return outport
},


 async TrackLoop(stack, input, systems, lines) {
    var set = new Set();
    
    while (!this.isEmpty(stack)) {
        
        var obj = this.remove(stack);


        if (obj.type == 'system') {
            var s = obj;

            var outport = [];

           //check if system is subsystem, yes: go inside and start trace
            if (s.blockType == 'SubSystem') {
            // outport of is array of OutPort inside subsystem
            // , it is used to find next line   
                outport = await this.handleSubsystem(s, oldObj )
            }
                             
            if (s.blockType == 'Outport') {
                set.add(s)
            }

            // When outport.length = 0, it means 
            // the line originates from a normal block. Like line1 and line2
            if (outport.length == 0) {
                var lineResult = this.findLine(s, lines)
                this.add(stack, lineResult);
            }

           // When outport.length != 0, it means 
           // the line originates from a subsystem. Like line3
            else {
                outport.forEach(port => {
                // line is found by outport system of subsystem
                var lineResult = this.findLine(s, lines, port) 
                this.add(stack, lineResult);
                })
            }
        }

        if (obj.type == 'line') {
            var lineResult = obj;
            var s = this.findSystem(lineResult, systems)
            this.add(stack, s);
        }

        var oldObj = obj;
    }
    return [...set];
},
    async handleSubsystem(s, obj ) {
    var outport = []
    // Call Api to get new systems and lines inside a subsystem
    var { systems: newSystems, lines: newLines } = initEntities(s.id)

    // Call highlightSignal again to start trace
    // inside a subsystem, obj.dst is   lineResult.dst
    outport = await this.highlightSignal(input, newSystems, newLines, obj.dst)

    return outport;
},
```

When it's a small graph, it produces immediate results, but when dealing with a large graph containing large nested subgraphs within subsystems, it can cause blocking thread. How I can fix this problem

Comment: Please provide the code with which the data structure is initialised and your function is called, so that your problem can be reproduced by running the program. Your code is not valid on its own. There is a reference to `this`, to `initEntities`, `findSystem`, `this.findSystem`, `this.remove`, `this.isEmpty`, `this.add`, `this.findLine`, `this.findLineResult`, ... none of which are defined, and we cannot guess what they do or return.